# How to create a CNAME a DNS name at the level abc.xyz.mydomain.com (sub-sub-domain) if my DNS host only supports xyz.mydomain.com (sub-domain)?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record

I need to create the CNAME record:

abc.xyz.mydomain.com = verify.azure.com

but my DNS provider (www.freeparking.com) only allows me to create it at the sub-domain level (i.e. xyz.mydomain.com). I have confirmed with the technical support that the cannot create a CNAME at the sub-sub-domain level (i.e. abc.xyz.mydomain.com).

Is there a way I can create a sub-sub-domain level (i.e. abc.xyz.mydomain.com) CNAME record by referencing DNS names? If not, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question lacks technical rigor, probably due to a lack of knowledge about how DNS works, so I am going to assume you mean the following:

- you own domain example.com, which is registered at www.freeparking.com, who also provide you with name services for this domain.
- you wish to create a DNS entry called some.thing.example.com, and point this at something
- your registrar/hosting provider says they cannot oblige

If this is correct, get a better hosting provider; [**zoneedit.com**](http://www.zoneedit.com/), for example, is free and allows you to do anything that is valid in a DNS zone.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I do understand DNS, but I thought sub-sub-domain would be a clearer term as I've seen other people use that :-) Thanks for the info.

Comment: +1 yes, get a better DNS host.

Answer (score 3):

By sub-sub domain I assume you mean x.y.domain.com.  And by freeparking.com not supporting it I assume you mean their DNS management system doesn't allow you to add x.y as a CNAME record.

I think you will need to switch domain providers, or use a different nameserver, since Azure will surely be looking at the authoratitive name server for authentication.

Are you sure that Azure require you to register a sub-sub domain for authentication?

Comment: 'Are you sure that Azure require you to register a sub-sub domain for authentication?'. It's what they are asking for in their Management Portal, but I could e-mail them to see if there is another method. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave an example of what they are actually asking for - obfuscated if you are paranoid about sharing your domain name on this forum :-)